# csproj keeps losing referenced project references in VS2017 using new csproj format

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, csproj

My csproj has the following lines:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk" ToolsVersion="15.0">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Deterministic>False</Deterministic>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\blah.Common\blah.Common.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\blah.Model\blah.Model.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

The referenced projects build fine. However in the VS tree these two projects randomly disappear from the Dependencies tree and VS reports the references as missing and the build passes.

Reloading/rebuilding/cleaning/restarting/removing then adding the projects again in no particular order usually fixes it. Problem comes back after a legitimate build error crops up in another project.

I am using Resharper and VS2017

I have tried dotnet restore with no luck. Any ideas why this one particular project is constantly losing its references?

Edit: I just realised I incorrectly mentioned the build as FAILING. It does not fail and builds successfully, however my project is litered with red errors and warnings saying references are missing. After a successful build the red warnings/errors disappear then randomly come back again.

Sometimes the projects are literally missing from the references tree, other times they are visible. When right clicking "add reference" the project is already ticked however. Unloading the project and reloading or doing a full rebuild fixes the "Error" only for it to come back at some point.

Even though the "Error List" is filled with missing reference errors, a clean and full build produces no errors and creates a successful build.

Comment: Can you include a minimal repo using newly created projects or are you able to share a build log? (`/bl` argument to the `msbuild` or `dotnet` command > `msbuild.binlog` file - but will contain names of files involved as well as paths and environment variables of your system)

Comment: Next time the problem comes up I will create a build log.

Comment: How do I add /bl to the build environment via VS 2017? I cant find where to specify custom msbuild arguments.

Comment: you need to do that from a command line build (developer command prompt > `msbuild /bl` in the solution dir). If it doesn't occur on command line builds, it is probably even weirder

Comment: @MartinUllrich I have some build logs but I can't make them public. I will msg you the links to them if you are able to give any insight it would be very much appreciated. How can I contact you?

Answer (score 4):

Did you check the .NET framework version that these 3 projects are targeting?

Incompatibility between framework versions allows the reference to get added but results in missing references during build/run time. To validate if this is indeed the problem, you can check the warnings that Visual Studio produces while building the solution. An alternative way of finding the root cause of the problem, would be to add one of the projects as a DLL reference while keeping the other as a project reference. If the DLL reference doesn't work, it means there is some configuration mismatch between the source and target projects (e.g. .NET framework version). If the DLL version works, then it means Project References are broken, in which case you can check if path provided is correct.

Comment: I will try those things and report back

Comment: I was going nuts with those disappearing references... You'd think VS would give you a reason... Also happening in VS 2019